# Flexbox align first item in relation with a centered image grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've a grid of fixed size images. The number of images for each line grows with the width of the window. This can be seen in the following snippet:

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.thumbnail {
  margin: 0 1em 2em
}

.title {
  flex: 1 100%;
  width: 300px
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <h1 class="title">Cats</h1>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats/1" alt=""></a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats/2" alt=""></a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats/3" alt=""></a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats/4" alt=""></a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats/5" alt=""></a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats/6" alt=""></a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats/7" alt=""></a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats/8" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

My question is how could the `.title` be aligned with the top left of the first image?

[image]

Comment: well a first idea is to use media query as you only have 2 situations. 2 images or 1 image so it can be easy .. unless the max-width will change

Comment: another idea is to simply wrap the title with the first image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that you have fixed width set on the images and a maximum width on the `list`, you can use a pseudo to balance the `title` with.

What makes this work is that the `title` and pseudo is simply positioned in the same way, and with the same logic, as the images are, and by that always push the 1st cat to the next row.

*If you need 3 images or more in a row, use a media query to control the width of the pseudo.*

*Note, I also changed the photo's to dummy image's since the cats for some reason won't load properly all the time.*

Stack snippet

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.thumbnail {
  margin: 0 1em 2em;
}

.title {
  width: 300px;                  /*  match the title/images width/margin  */
  margin: 0 0.5em 1em;           /*  h1 default font is 2em, so we need only 0.5 here  */
  order: -1;                     /*  move before the pseudo  */
}

.list::before {                  /*  added pseudo  */
  content: '';
  width: 300px;                  /*  match the title/images width/margin  */
  margin: 0 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <h1 class="title">Cats</h1>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300/ddd?text=cat 1" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300/ddd?text=cat 2" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300/ddd?text=cat 3" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300/ddd?text=cat 4" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300/ddd?text=cat 5" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300/ddd?text=cat 6" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: i guess i would also consider adding the :after element like that we cover until 3 images and if more we add media query

Comment: @TemaniAfif With 3 in a row, adding one more pseudo won't work w/o a media query. Try and you'll see what happens when the first wrap occurs and there will be 2 in a row. The last pseudo will push the first cat to the right, leaving only 1 cat in that row, right aligned.

Comment: hmm yes right .. i was thinking it will work like we was in the last row :) but it seems more complicated with the first row ... but this desevere a +1, not sure why your last attempt got downvoted :/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks...and as my 2 last answer got downvoted within minutes, I guess someone was "paying back" for something :) ... also with this answer, when image's doesn't load properly, it offset the whole thing, so it could been that, hence I changed the photos

Comment: haha true :) i also had this "paying back" a lot of time ;) .Well, people sometimes don't like when you highlight their errors or disagree with them.

Comment: @LGSon Thank you for posting this back, for a moment I thought I was delusional since I saw the answer soon in the morning but hadn't time to read till later discover that there was nothing here xP

Comment: I do like the fact there is no relation with the first image, I'll play a bit to see how this fits on context. I do appreciate a lot the all the responses here and the time to find a solution! As a side comment, don't you feel that still feels like a hack solution? I feel frustrated a lot of times width CSS, because of this, many times there is no clean solutions...

Comment: @LGSon yeah, lorempixel.com for some reason is can be very slow... felt the same but I did like the cats anyway.

Comment: Nice detail there "h1 default font is 2em, so we need only 0.5 here"

Comment: Any solution that needs an extra element to allow for a certain effect are IMHO a hack, so whether that extra element is placed in the markup (which can be done in the above case too), or rendered using a legit pseudo element, I consider equal. The main issue here is to allow for the text to align left with the images, though since their parent won't _resize_ when the items wrap, there is no _known left edge_ since the `justify-content: center;` is used, hence we need a _trick_ to find that _left edge_. When a wrap occur and can be detected using CSS, then there will be a _hack_ free solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want there to be a connection between the header and the first image, then spell that out in the code.

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 3em auto 0;
}

.thumbnail {
  margin: 0 1em 2em;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <h1 class="title">Cats</h1>
    <a href=""><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats/1" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats/2" alt=""></a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats/3" alt=""></a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats/4" alt=""></a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats/5" alt=""></a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats/6" alt=""></a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats/7" alt=""></a>
  <a href="" class="thumbnail"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats/8" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vqf7q06e/3/)

Comment: we can avoid `position:absolute` and use `align-items: flex-end;` with the container :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, not sure what you mean. Post an update here to my jsfiddle demo. Or post an answer.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Wow. Nice alternative. You should post an answer .

Comment: well i think i will simply update yours if you don't mind as we will be very close if i post it as an answer ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, whatever you prefer. But having both options may be useful. Just use my code and post your solution in an answer if you want.

Comment: +1 Definitely it works. The `flex-end` is ingenious! **I would prefer a solution were there is no relation with the first image**, since the title describes the list of images, not the first one. I guess its more a semantic issue that a practical problem. Any way I'll leave it open to see if any other ideas would come up. @TemaniAfif now there the code provided does not match the jsFiddle demo... :) its somehow confusing, should I edit the demo and provide a new link? =P

Comment: @a--m it's updated ;) by the way both was similar i simply forget to remove position:relative :) by the way there is was solution provided by LGSon where there is no relation, but it was deleted ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Was at work and needed to fix it, so deleted it. Now re-posted.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this and found another solution that I would like to share:

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.thumbnail {
  flex: 1 auto;
  margin: 0 1em 2em
}

.title {
  flex: 1 100%;
  margin: 0 0.5em 1em;
  order: 0;
}

@media all and (min-width: 700px) {
  .list {
    max-width: calc((300px + 2em) * 2);
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1100px) {
  .list {
    max-width: calc((300px + 2em) * 3);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="list">
    <h1 class="title">Cats</h1>
    <a href="" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300/ddd?text=cat 1" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300/ddd?text=cat 2" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300/ddd?text=cat 3" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300/ddd?text=cat 4" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300/ddd?text=cat 5" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300/ddd?text=cat 6" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Why?**

- no relation between the title and the first thumbnail.
- since I need to increase the `min-width` of the `.list` and having as reference the [LGSon answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48670721/220272) I end up having problems to setup the media-queries, the values where the list break into more columns are difficult to get.

**How?**

Simply following the [Temani Afif comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654097/flexbox-align-first-item-in-relation-with-a-centered-image-grid/48670721#comment84306319_48654097) and use media-queries that constrain the all `.list` `width`, this way I can predict different layouts and the title will be constrained within this width.

---

> I'm accepting LGSon answer since the original question did not mention the fact that the `.list` `width` could change. Apart from that it would solve my issue without introducing a relation between the `title` and the first image.